# Why is $\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} = 0$ in Ito lemma with $f(X,t) = \ln(X)$ when $f$ is a function of $X(t)$ which is a function of $t$

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

For a stochastic process $X(t)$ and Brownian motion $Z(t)$

$$
d X = a(X, t) d t + b(X,t) d Z
$$

where $d Z \sim \mathcal{N}(0, d t)$. Ito's lemma is defined as:

$$
d f = \left( \frac{\partial f}{\partial t} + a\frac{\partial f}{\partial X} + \frac{b^2}{2} \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial X^2} \right) d t + b \frac{\partial f}{\partial X} d Z
$$
where $a$ and $b$ are shorthand for $a(X,t)$ and $b(X,t)$.

If we apply this to a process $X(t)$ defined as $d X = \mu X d t + \sigma X d Z$ with $f(X,t) = \ln(X)$ then the book I am reading states that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} = 0$. I do not understand why the partial derivative of $f()$ wrt $t$ is 0 when f is a function of $X(t)$ which is a function of $t$.

In particular, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial X} \frac{d X}{d t}$ and neither of them are 0 so how can $\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} $ be 0? I can only assume that this chain rule application is wrong and this must be because the chain rule does not work with random variables?

Comment: I wouldn't say that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial X} \frac{d X}{d t}$. At most I would write (not relevant for this problem) $\frac{d f}{dt} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial X} \frac{d X}{d t}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're overthinking this:  $\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}$ is a partial derivative and so you hold to the $x$ coordinate constant.  More specifically, it's perhaps more clear if its written in a more formal fashion.

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ and let $f_t,f_x$ and $f_{xx}$ denote its partial derivatives.  Then Ito's formula says:

$$d f(t,X_t) = \left(f_t(t,X_t) + a f_x(t,X_t) + \frac{b^2}{2} f_{xx}(t,X_t) \right)\,dt + b f_x(t,X_t)\,dZ\,.$$

In other words, the point of Ito's formula is that those derivatives are **just considering $f$ as a function**.